# How to track down memory leaks with MongoMapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-management, memory-leaks, heroku, mongomapper

I've read that Oink is a great tool for tracking ActiveRecord apps, but I'm using MongoMapper. Are there equivalent tools that can help me identify memory issues? My app lives on Heroku and consistently hits the 512MB memory threshold so I'd like to understand what's causing that.

Comment: I am in the same situation : an Heroku application that uses MM is leaking.  Have you found a solution ?

Comment: Didn't find any good profiling tools, but I did reduce the memory errors I'm getting by adding more mongo indexes, analyzing performance with the Mongo Database Profiler and adding another Web Dyno.

Comment: Thank you.  That's strange that the memory is growing up like that (I have the same in development).

Answer (score 0):

Oink will work just as well for diagnosing memory leaks with Mongo as it will with ActiveRecord.

You can also use profiling tools like NewRelic in local development mode to check where you're spending your time, when you're triggering garbage collection, and what mongo/sql queries are being executed.  This is my favorite tool for identifying and testing fixes for performance problems.

https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/